how to prove a function exists (simple example)
This question arises because I am a self-teaching beginner - and am new to proof patterns and strategies.
I asked a similar question but the replies were overly complex because the exercise was complex, and they missed answering the actual question. So, the following is a simpler example (which I made up).

Given a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, which maps as $f(x)=x^2$, show there exists a function $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $h \equiv f \circ f$.

What would I do to show $h$ exists? Would I do the following?

show $h$ has a domain - in this case $\mathbb{R}$
show $h$ has a codomain - in this case $\mathbb{R}$
make explicit what the mapping is - in this case $h(x)=x^4$
and demonstrate that the definition doesn't contradict the need for functions to map an element of the domain to a single element of the codomain - in this case $h(x)=x^4$ maps to a single element of the domain

Is that all we need to do to show a function exists?

Not following.  We have $h$ explicitly.  It's $x^4$, just as you say.

hi @lulu - i know from learning basic set theory that simply describing a set does not make it a set. I am wondering what I need to show to prove a set exists. Perhaps I am overthinking this, but I suspect that there are specific criteria that need to be met to show a function exists?

If you are working off a particular set of axioms and definitions, follow those.  But it's hard to guess what you intend here...why is $f(x)$ a function?  That is, why is $x^2$ clearly a function, but not $x^4$?

The question rephrased is "Can we apply a function multiple times?", which means the function's output becomes its input at the second application - this means we have to check, if the domain covers the codomain, otherwise we have to define restrictions on the first application's input - which in turn changes the function definition itself and narrows the domain, so we have to iteratively do the check again. Even if we don't do this and there are outputs that can't be inputs, I wouldn't say that the function "doesn't exist", only if no output could be input - if not that's the case, I would say the function is "not well defined".
